# Unable to start critical Windows Services in Docker Windows Container

Tags: docker, containers, windows-services, windows-container

We are trying to modernize a legacy 3rd party application by setting up a Docker Windows Container. We are using windows image: `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/server:ltsc2022` for our container. This application needs some of the service to be running, however the windows container itself restricts the services from turning on. Some of the services we require are: 'Base Filtering Engine (BFE)', 'Network Location Awareness (NlaSvc)', 'Network List Service (netprofm)', 'Server (LanmanServer)', etc.
There is also a GitHub unresolved closed issue with similar issue: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/173
Any advice or solution is welcome.

Thank You,
Maharshi Suthar

Answer (score 0):

The reason Windows containers restricts these services is because some of their components are shared with the host. This is an expected behavior on Windows containers and in this case, the app running on a container should not be requiring these.
I understand from your comment above that you don't have access to the code of this application, so my recommendation is to add a comment on that GitHub issue stating your case, so Microsoft can prioritize this issue.